# Construct a list of permuted circles containing arrows

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics

I am drawing a picture as

containing several raws addressed by any permutation of three circles with different radii.
My difficulties to solve which I need clues are:

1- Inserting an arrow inside any circle with an arbitrary direction for example `30 degrees` or `57 degrees`

2-Implementation of a permutation between circles to construct all raws

3-Inserting the symbols of minus-plus alongside raws.

I can just draw a circle without any arrow inside it. Furthermore, I have problems to implement a permutation between circles.
Can anyone give me a clue?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You have to demonstrate your attempts.

Comment: If you don't want to give any hint please don't repeat an unimportant talk "What have you tried so far" . I did not invite you to solve my problem.

Answer (score 6):

```
arrowlist = 
  Flatten@Table[
    Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, r], Thickness[0.02], Arrowheads[.1], 
      Arrow[{{-.9 r Cos[\[Theta]], -.9 r Sin[\[Theta]]}, {.9 r Cos[\
\[Theta]], .9 r Sin[\[Theta]]}}]}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {\[Theta], 
    -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/24}, {r, .3, 1, .1}];
```

[image]

```
GraphicsRow@
 Join[{Graphics[Text[Style[RandomChoice[{"+", "-"}], 48]]]}, 
  RandomChoice[arrowlist, 3]]
```

Comment: Thankx for the hint but the circles should have a different radius

Comment: There is nothing whatsoever about different radii in the quesiton.

Comment: you are right. I modified it.